# How to disable cloud sync of __astcache files in C++Builder 11.3?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I upgraded from 10.4 to 11.3 C++Builder Community Edition.

In 10.4, I somehow found a way to disable the `__astcache` files, which are very annoying because I sync everything to my cloud, and this sucks enormous bandwidth. But I can't remember how.

How can I disable it in 11.3?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop any files being written to __astcache by going to

Project->Options->C++ Compiler->LSP

and uncheck all the options.

However, this will disable code indexing and other useful IDE features, which will prevent the IDE from assisting you in coding and finding declarations...

Then again, the indexing takes ages with a large project and often hangs for no obvious reason, that you may not miss it...

Another alternative is to configure your cloud synchronization to ignore the files in __astcache folders, if whatever tool you use allows that.

Comment: Thanks, I did just rely on configuring the sync to ignore all files matching c@@*